# What is the purpose of CaO in Oakwood reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-reduction

In the Oakwood reaction, i.e.
$$\ce{RCOOH ->[NaOH + CaO] RH + Na2CO3},$$
is there any role or importance of $\ce{CaO}$, because it doesn't appear to be anywhere in the product.

Comment: Sodium hydroxide plus calcium oxide forms soda lime. Its use purely handling convenience, it has a high surface area for reaction and is far less hygroscopic than solid sodium hydroxide powder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sodium hydroxide plus calcium oxide forms soda lime. Its use is mainly down to handling covenience as it is far less hygroscopic than powdered sodium hydroxide.

Comment: Well, now your comment is obsolete, also it would be good if answer was longer then comment ;)